# Remove letters from my numeric columns doesn't work

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `x_train` like this (all the columns are `object` type):

```
a     b    c
1      2   523f
2     45   52A
3     32    95
4    245    84A
5     86    42
6      7    52
7     45    31
7a    45    712
8b    53    62
194v  34    3
```

The `Y_train` only have 0 and 1. I tried to use `RF.fit(x_train, Y_train)` but I got an error:

`could not convert string to float: 7a`

I try to have only the numeric value and remove the letters, so I tried to use something like:

```
x_train = re.findall(r'\d+\d+', x['a'])
```

but it doesn't work. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming all integers, you can use this for any column that has non-numeric values:

```
df[col] = df[col].str.replace('\D', '', regex=True).astype(int)
```